# Вопрос по aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

Отправляю post запрос на сайт с заголовками:

```
ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Cookie": "temp_user=162609829638675; _ga=GA1.2.2008870868.1626098297; _gid=GA1.2.589339928.1626790087; SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=1; SL_wptGlobTipTmp=1",
        "Host": "test.com",
        "sec-ch-ua": '''" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"''',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "User-Agent": ua.random
    }
```

Отправляю запрос через aiohttp:

```
async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('test.com/', headers=headers) as response:
            print(response.headers)
```

Когда пытаюсь получить ответ от сайта с моими отправленными заголовками, получаю в `print` только это:

```
<CIMultiDictProxy('Date': 'Sat, 24 Jul 2021 11:12:30 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; preload', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '5786', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')>
```

Мои вопросы таковы: Как убедиться в том, что я действительно отправляю все заголовки в словаре `headers`, мне это необходимо, чтобы при частой отправке запросов, сайт не подумал, что его пытается кто-то парсить или ещё что-либо сделать, как безопасно можно отправлять запросы, чтобы в дальнейшем не получить ошибки 403 Forbidden?.

Comment: Вроде бы await respose. Нет?

Comment: Нет, так ошибка появляется `TypeError: object multidict._multidict.CIMultiDictProxy can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: Если вы хотите максимально надёжно проерить отправляемые заголовки, то тут только отправлять запрос на свой сервер и там на сервере смотреть, что в него пришло